# Apache loadbalancer can be used for HTTPS and PHP servers

Tags: php, apache, ssl, https, load-balancing

I need a software load balancer in frontend, and two PHP servers in backend.

Clients will send request to the frontend using HTTPS.

I've read a lot of articles around this subject, but I can't verify if apache is able to loadbalance a https communication. This is not very clear for me.

Can I use apache for this ? Or which free loadbalancers supports ssl (HaProxy doesn't support it in its stable release) ?

Comment: nginx in proxy mode on the front end load balancer and 2 nginx or apache servers behind.

Comment: Yes, you can use Apache for SSL load balancing. You need to terminate the SSL at the load balancer and then proxy the requests to your application servers.

Comment: thanks for you two answers which are interesting